# Two not greedy patterns in the same regex does not match shortest substring

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to remove surrounding xml tags without using xml library, just with regular expressions :

```
s="<tr></tr><tr><td>stuff</td></tr><tr></tr>"
print re.sub(r'<tr>.*?stuff.*?</tr>',r'stuff_without_first_bounding_tr',s)
```

It prints :

```
stuff_without_first_bounding_tr<tr></tr>
```

I was expecting :

```
<tr></tr>stuff_without_first_bounding_tr<tr></tr>
```

I am using .*? two times, both should be non greedy (shortest solution should be taken)
Why only the second one is non greedy ?
What regex should I use ?

Comment: **Why** do you have to use regex?

Comment: I am creating jinja2 xml templates for python-docx. Jinja2 tags must be outside the xml usual flow, it will be much faster with regex than lxml... I hope...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a negative lookahead assertion.

```
>>> s="<tr></tr><tr><td>stuff</td></tr><tr></tr>"
>>> re.sub(r'<tr>(?:(?!</?tr>).)*stuff(?:(?!</?tr>).)*</tr>',r'stuff_without_first_bounding_tr',s)
'<tr></tr>stuff_without_first_bounding_tr<tr></tr>'
```

`(?:(?!</?tr>).)*` first checks that the character going to be matched won't be the `<` symbol followed by optional forward slash and `tr>` . If yes, then it would match the corresponding character. We all know that the `*` repeats the previous token zero or more times, so `(?:(?!</?tr>).)*` the condition will be checked before matching each character. If a particular character failed to satisfy the condition then the match will be failed.

Comment: Really don't need lookahead. `re.sub(r'(<tr></tr>).*?(<tr></tr>)',r'\1stuff_without_first_bounding_tr\2',s)`

Comment: Yes **specific** while other cases should use a parser.

Comment: @hwnd yep, mine also won't work if there is newline present in -between. In that case we need to use DOTALL modifier. And i won't provide this answer if op wants a parser instead of regex but he wants the opposite..